# Get completion status from Marathon?

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am running WordPress sites using [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon).

First I hit the Marathon POST API to create app, then I hit the Marathon PUT API with the environment variables (database-related).

Marathon takes some time to start the app (until that time, it is restarting because of a database error).

How can I know when the Marathon App is ready?  Does Marathon have an API hook indicating when the app is successfully started?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the status of all running apps the using [/v2/apps/](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#get-v2-apps) endpoint. This includes information about the running/staged tasks.

```
"tasksRunning": 2,
"tasksHealthy": 2,
"tasksUnhealthy": 0,
"tasksStaged": 0,
```

Another alternative is to check the [/v2/deployments](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#get-v2-deployments) endpoint until all deployments are finished.

Otherwise it is easy to see in the webinterface, but that probably doesn't help you :-).